# Even modified the locale and system calendar but Mobile Center license still use Thai Land Buddhist calendar

Tags: microfocus-mobile-center

Has changed the locale and calendar of the MC, but when install the license of the MC, we still get it started from 1/27/1475

Answer (score 0):

MC using in-correct setting of Language and Region of Windows instead of the locale or calendar of the system.
you can refer to this link:
[Change Windows System Language](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-properly-change-system-default-language-windows-10)

you can delete the license data with Server DB (pgadmin3 of the server).
and re-upload your license again after changing the region and language.